# How to compute precision, recall, F1 and confusion matrix of Multiclass-problem with MobileNet

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I created a model for mask-detection through the transfer learning of a MobileNet CNN, for a multiclass problem: NoMask, Mask, UncorrectMask.

Below is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator


IMAGE_SIZE = (224, 224)
IMG_SHAPE = IMAGE_SIZE + (3,)
DATASET_DIR = "./DATASET/Mask_Detection/"
BATCH_SIZE = 32 
EPOCHS = 15

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    validation_split = 0.2,
    rescale = 1./255, #per processare più velocemente i dati
    brightness_range=[1,2]
)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    DATASET_DIR,
    target_size = IMAGE_SIZE,
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
    class_mode = "categorical",
    subset = "training"
)

test_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    DATASET_DIR,
    target_size = IMAGE_SIZE,
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
    class_mode = "categorical",
    subset = "validation"
)

mobielNetV2 = tensorflow.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,include_top=False,weights='imagenet')

for layer in mobielNetV2.layers: 
    layer.trainable = False

x = Flatten()(mobielNetV2.output)
prediction = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(inputs=mobielNetV2.input, outputs=prediction)
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

r = model.fit(train_generator, validation_data=test_generator, epochs=EPOCHS,steps_per_epoch=len(train_generator),validation_steps=len(test_generator))
model.save("MobileNet.h5")
```

I have a problem, I would like to calculate the **precision**, **recall**, **F1** and **confusion matrix** for my model, but I can't figure out how to do it, can someone help me?
I was able to easily calculate the accuracy and logloss.

Comment: You could use tensorflow's confusion matrix function given some labels and predictions: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/confusion_matrix 
Then precision/recall/F1 can be derived from that.

Answer (score 0):

See [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/audio/simple_audio#evaluate_the_model_performance). Basically you should get your model's predictions on your test set by

```py
y_pred_logits = model.predict(test_generator)
y_pred = tf.math.argmax(y_pred_logits)
```

The link above also has a example for displaying the confusion matrix.

Precision, recall and F1 could be computed with sklearn as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9092866/11664800.